# NVDA + Chrome not reading part of my website

Tags: google-chrome, accessibility, screen-readers, nvda

NVDA is not reading a div with the main content of my website. It doesn't work on Chrome + NVDA.
It works well on iOs VoiceOver, Chrome + Screen Reader Extension, Firefox + NVDA.
It reads other elements of the page, like header and footer. I can navigate all elements of the page with TAB button, but NVDA doesn't read them.

It can be fixed by resizing browser's window and forcing chrome to redraw the content or by adding empty span to the document.

I think it is a Chrome not NVDA issue. If I check chrome://accessibility/ it doesn't list missing element.

Any advice how to solve or debug it?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with only the relevant code that clearly demonstrates this particular issue?

Comment: No, I was not able to create such example.

Comment: Maybe someone else will try.

Comment: It works on Chrome Canary, so I think it is related to some bug in Chrome.

Comment: The beauty of a jsfiddle is everyone usually has a different browser and can easily browser test this for you in less than a minutes time.

Comment: Initially same as @Szymon. NVDA is only working on Chrome Canary version 102.0.4976.0 but not on Chrome version. However when I closed all instances of chrome and then restarted a single one again it worked.